# MouseDown event handler seem to block Click event handler from being invoked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling

I'm doing an online course on event handling in WPF. In a section about tunneling and bubbling events I'm told to use the following code sample to track the sequence of events being fired (using breakpoints):

**View:**

```
<Grid PreviewMouseDown="Grid_PreviewMouseDown">
    <Button Name="btnFirst" Width="200" Height="200" Click="Button_Click">
        <Image MouseDown="Image_MouseDown" Source="Assets/pic.jpg"></Image>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Grid_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    { // Breakpoint goes here

    }

    private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    { // Breakpoint goes here

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { // Breakpoint goes here

    }
}
```

**Results:**

[image: resulting app]

In the course, clicking on the image triggers all three event handlers, but when I try it, only **Grid_PreviewMouseDown** and **Image_MouseDown** are invoked, **Button_Click** seems to be completely ignored. Is this an expected behavior or am I missing something here? The course is from 2014 btw.

One thing I've noticed is that **Button_Click** is invoked only if I remove **PreviewMouseDown** attribute from the Grid tag and I click on the button itself (not on an image inside).

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, all three events are called when clicking the button or the image inside. You wrote 
"// Breakpoint goes here"
in your code sample in the `Button_Click` handler, does it mean that it's working as expected or not? This is confusing. Also I don't see it in your code but make sure you don't write `e.Handled = true` in your `Image_MouseDown` handler as it would indeed stop the event propagation.

Comment: @CorentinPane The "breakpoint goes here comment" indicates where I put breakpoints in Visual Studio to check which methods are invoked. The methods are empty, there's no code setting the the Handled property on an event.

Comment: Oh okay I misunderstood, I though you meant the breakpoint was *hitting* where you put your comments, my mistake. It's very weird that it doesn't work for you. Could you please upload and share your whole solution so I could have a closer look?

Comment: @CorentinPane, there you go:
https://github.com/RafalDardzinski/Events-Test

Comment: you just uploaded an empty project, there is no code and no xaml in your `MainWindow` :/

Comment: @CorentinPane yeah, sorry, not used to work with git extension in Visual Studio. Added it now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201140/discussion-between-corentin-pane-and-rufus1530).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we ran out of other options, I suggest you re-install the latest version of Visual Studio with all workload packages associated to .NET Framework and WPF development - there might have been some corruption at some point.

Comment: turned out this was a problem with my version of Visual Studio 2017 - updating it through Visual Studio Installer solved the issue entirely. Thanks for the help man, cheers!